# Instance of Inner Class

Tags: apex, java

How to update argument of inner class instance ?

This is the explanation :

```
public class {
    constructor {
        Initialize Inner class Instance(arg1)
    }
    method {
        variable arg2;
        same instance with different argument(arg2) ** //how to do** this
    }

    public inner class {
        inner class constructor(...) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ParentClassName.InnerClassName obj=new ParentClassName.InnerClassName(arg1);` This way you can initialize inner class object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to set inner class members. Access to members depends of their protection level.

example for Public

```
 public inner class {
 public integer I;
 inner class constructor(integer input){
    I = input;
    }
 }

//in this case you can access members directly 
ParentClassName.InnerClassName classInstance=new ParentClassName.InnerClassName(123);
classInstance.I=124;
```

example for Private (access is restricted only for outer classes, not the parent)

```
 public inner class {
 private integer I;
 inner class constructor(integer input){
    I = input;
    }
 public void setI(integer input){
     i=input;
     }
 }

//in this case you can not access members directly 
ParentClassName.InnerClassName classInstance=new ParentClassName.InnerClassName(123);
classInstance.setI(124);
```